# Mathematica is blocking my Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, freeze

I downloaded Mathematica 12.2 as a product from Wolfram web. I installed from terminal as in Ubuntu 18.04. When I open a Mathematica notebook everything looks normal, but after I close it my computer freezes, and it is not possible to do anything. The only option that I have is to turn off the power by pressing the button at the bottom close to the keyboard.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to tell with the picture ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'blocked'.

Comment: it stops the computer, I mean, after close mathematica it is not possible to do anything more in the laptop, the only way to use the laptop again is turning it off from the bottom close to the keyboard

Comment: With the picture I try to show how it looks like after close mathematica, it remains in this form and it is no possible to do anything more.

Comment: Does Alt-Tab do anything?

Comment: It does not anything